# How Can I use RestKit, in Objective C, to map latitude and longitude fields into a single CLLocationCoordinate2D?

Tags: objective-c, restkit

I'm using RestKit to read from a REST API. Here is an excerpt of the JSON:

```
{"id":1,
"name":"Location 1",
"description":"Description for location 1",
"created_at":"2015-08-29T13:29:16.326Z",
"latitude":"23.1522671072",
"longitude":"-9.4321711561",
...
```

However, in my application the latitude & longitude are encapsulated within:

```
@property (nonatomic) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
```

What is the best way to transform the two latitude & longitude fields into a CLLocationCoordinate2D field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code snippet may help you.

```
NSString *latStr = response[@"latitude"];
NSString *longStr = response[@"latitude"];

double latitude = [latStr doubleValue];
double longitude = [longStr doubleValue];

self.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude);
```

Comment: Yeah, this is the approach that I first thought of, and will probably use. I was wondering if there's a way to do this using RKObjectMapping.

Comment: @brwhyan I don't think so ;)